# how to use CruiseControl.Net to do automatic build for Asp.net 4.0 web application

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, asp.net-4.0

I am new to Cruise-control.Net and Automatic build concepts. Could you please suggest me how to use cruise control.net to perform automatic build for a sample asp.net 4.0 build application. Please let me know what are the prerequisites in order to use Cruise-control.net

Answer (score 0):

If you are using visual studio, it will give you a project file (.csproj or. vbproj). 
You can use the msbuild task in cruise control to build this project which will build the website. 
If you need to you can execute aspnet_compiler to compile/validate the other resources in your website, such as in line code in an aspx Page, or. Cshtml razor views.

There should be no other prerequisites for cruise control to do this.

Comment: Msbuild is part of the. Net framework not visual studio. Therefore you don't need to install visual studio on the cruise control machine. 
Be aware that if there are any auto generated serialisation assemblies then you may have issues. 
Visual studio uses a different version of sgen which isn't installed as part of the .Net framework.

Answer (score 0):

A blog post I wrote a while ago is just what you're looking for. [Continuous Integration with Cruise Control .NET](http://enterpriseyness.com/2009/12/continuous-integration-with-cruise-control-net-nant/)

This method doesn't require you to have Visual Studio installed on your build machine. You will need to have .NET 4.0 installed on the build server, though.